# How to access to Android Settings from my application?

Tags: android

I wanna getting access to Android Settings from my application with a click of button in Activity A, after this when user click the back button in Settings, it will bring the user to Activity B...

The code below that I am running, is able to bring me to Settings from Activity A, but when I am in the Settings page and click the back button, it brings me back to Activity A, can someone teach me how to do in order to bring me to Activity B when i click back button in Settings?

```
 startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int REQUEST_CODE = 5;
startActivityForResult (new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS),REQUEST_CODE); // call instead startActivity

  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // return from settings
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this,ActivityB.class));// start Activity B
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: void is an invalid type for the variable onActivityResult

Comment: startActivityForResult is the function that you should call instead  startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS));